# Run inner div click event when pressing outer div or vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click, onclicklistener

Is it possible to make inner div click when clicking outer div or make outer div click while pressing inner div. At the end I want both div to get click when pressing any div

```js
const outer = () => {
  console.log('clicked outer div')
}

const inner = () => {
  console.log('clicked innder div')
}
```

```css
.outer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  heigth: 50px;
  weigth: 50px;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  heigth: 50px;
  weigth: 50px;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" onClick="outer()">
  Outer Div
  <div class="inner" onClick="inner()">
    Innder Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not have a single `onClick` on the outer div?

Answer (score 0):

A single event listener on the parent element should be enough. Events *bubble* up. So ever time `inner` gets clicked, the event travels through the parents, passing `outer`. From the `outer` element you can examine the event by checking the `Event` object. That object is automatically available in each event listener and will tell you what the event is, what element triggered the event, and so on.

In the example below I'm using a single event listener on the `outer` element and read the `target` property of the `event` object to determine the element that has been clicked. It then outputs the `class` of the element into the `console.log` string.

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

outer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(`clicked ${event.target.className} div`);
});
```

```css
.outer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  Outer Div
  <div class="inner">
    Inner Div
  </div>
</div>
```